# how to edit WordPress Base Page

Tags: wordpress

I have an installation of Wordpress.Civicrm which I have copied to another server using a different domain name

It works great, except the WordPress Base Page is still set at the old domain name and I cannot find where to edit it

I have searched the database and the files, and cannot resolve this
it is shown on 
`my_website_domain/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1`

I want to change it

FROM

`my_OLD_domain_name/civicrm`

TO

`my_NEW_domain_name/civicrm`

I hope you can help

thankyou in advance

Neil

Answer (score 1):

You may find this wiki page helpful: [Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location)